# Does a python dynamic import of module generates .pyc?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-import, python-importlib

I would like to have dotted name strings that I can evaluate. Those dotted names could point to functions from new files the project do not know about (to quickly add a new functionality to the project without being part of the development team).

Right now, I resolve and compile the dotted names using a library (pyramid) then I save the compiled function object somewhere to be able to use it later.

I've seen that `importlib` let us import a module and it works perfectly fine, like so:

```
importlib.import_module('my_library')
```

Still, normally when you import a module, a `.pyc` will be generated so other calls won't take as much time to execute (as they won't have to be compiled again).

**Do imports using `importlib` create `.pyc` files?**

If not, would adding it to `locals()` change anything? (Adding it to `globals()` did not seem to work for me) Like so:

```
locals()['my_library'] = importlib.import_module('my_library')
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Seems easy to verify that way

Comment: "Still, normally when you import a module, a .pyc will be generated so other calls won't take as much time to execute (as they won't have to be compiled again)." What do you mean? AFAIK, they bytecode is compiled into memory, `pyc` files are so you don't have to re-compile each time your run your program, so it will affect start-up time, but not runtime after that

Comment: So having `importlib.import_module()` is ok (will not affect performance) even if that module is called often? So I could simply have it imported and used (as if already imported, the import will be skipped)?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.__import__) 1) "The __import__() function The import statement is syntactic sugar for this function." 2) "The import_module() function acts as a simplifying wrapper around importlib.__import__(). This means all semantics of the function are derived from importlib.__import__()."